# Symfony : clear cache and warmup when users are using the website

Tags: php, symfony, caching, symfony-3.4

With Symfony, when config or twig files are modified, the cache must be cleared and a warmup must be performed to take into account the new values.

My problem is when users are working on the website and I would like to update a file which needs a Symfony warmup command :  the command fails if a user is consulting the cache at the same times by browsing the website. Then the cache is corrupted and I need to run again the clear cache and the warmup command when users are angry because the website is not working and hit the F5 button again and again making this process endless...

To avoid this, I am always planning a maintenance and block website accessibility during the cache warmup.

But, it is a complex task to simply fix a typo, isn't it?

Is there a way to clear and warmup single file? Or any idea to handle this process correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me, might work for you.

I usually have two versions of my app placed side by side. Only one is connected to web server. If I have to make any changes I update inactive version, clear cache, warmup cache, etc. Then I switch active version in web server.

That way you have as much time as you want for maintenance and switch is unnoticeable for your users.

You can also configure web server to allow *inactive* version to be available in some internal channel. That way, after you done what you wanted to change you can peek if everything works as expected(or let testers do their work) before you go public.

Comment: Yes it could work. Except if database upgrade is needed, but in that case, the maintenance would be planned. Thanks for sharing your experience.

Comment: @sdespont If you can keep migrations backward compatible(at least to your last version) no maintenance downtime is needed. You update code, migrate, swap. Sometimes this requires you to split migration to couple parts, which takes more time(simple rename column takes 3 steps; create new column, migrate data, drop old one). We were able to deploy/update applications without downtime for couple years.

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to register a EventListener:

```
# /config/services.yaml
parameters:

    lockFilePath: "%kernel.root_dir%/../web/.lock"    

services:

    maintenance_listener:
        class: App\EventListener\MaintenanceListener
        arguments:
            - "%lockFilePath%"
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

Then the EventListener itself:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;

class MaintenanceListener
{
    private $lockFilePath;

    public function __construct($lockFilePath)
    {
        $this->lockFilePath = $lockFilePath;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        if ( ! file_exists($this->lockFilePath)) {
            return;
        }

        $event->setResponse(
          new Response(
            'site is in maintenance mode',
            Response::HTTP_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
          )
        );
        $event->stopPropagation();
    }
}
```

So if you now create a .lock file in /web then your site is in maintenance mode.
If you want to display a special template, you can inject @templating into the EventListener.

Comment: Thanks, I can do that with my web hosting. I was looking for a more transparent way... But, perhaps it is not possible.

Comment: Not sure if this would really solve the problem of the cache being rebuilt when a request comes in.  Doubtful if the listener would be called if the app never starts.